# What security layers of protection are available over XMPP?

Tags: encryption, tls, xmpp

I have been working on an application running over XMPP. I would like to know which all popular security layers are available over the XMPP protocol, similar to SSL over http.

Answer (score 6):

The [core XMPP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3920) defines how it [integrates with TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3920#section-5) for transport security, and [SASL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3920#section-6) for authentication.

There is also a standard [end-to-end signing and encryption protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3923) that can be used to ensure protection of messages from sender to ultimate recipient, whereas TLS only protects up to the next relay host. This end-to-end protocol builds on [S/MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME).

Also, depending on the context, you may have the option to put clients and servers in their own [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network), which will protect the traffic against outsiders. This is generic to every networked application and is done at the OS level.